# Split, clean and convert a list of list into dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a list of list as follows:

```
[['id：ZC0000218734', 'version： forth', 'date：2020-07-06'], ['v1：\n                            undefined', 'v2： undefined'], ['type：park', 'address：zhejiang...'], ['type：park', 'address：zhejiang...']]
```

How could I remove duplicate list (`ie: ['type：park', 'address：zhejiang...']`), split by `:`, clean `\n` and spaces, then convert it into a dataframe?

The expected result will like this:

```
             id version      date  ...         v2       type      address
0  ZC0000218734   forth  2020/7/6  ...  undefined  undefined  zhejiang...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try avoid double `split` with map and `str.strip` and then in nested list comprehension create dictionary, last pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [['id：ZC0000218734', 'version： forth', 'date：2020-07-06'], ['v1：\n                            undefined', 'v2： undefined'], ['type：park', 'address：zhejiang...'], ['type：park', 'address：zhejiang...']]
```

---

```
out = dict([map(str.strip, y.split('：')) for x in L for y in x])

df = pd.DataFrame([out])
print (df)
             id version        date         v1         v2  type      address
0  ZC0000218734   forth  2020-07-06  undefined  undefined  park  zhejiang...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [['id：ZC0000218734', 'version： forth', 'date：2020-07-06'], ['v1：\n                            undefined', 'v2： undefined'], ['type：park', 'address：zhejiang...'], ['type：park', 'address：zhejiang...']]

d = {v.split('：')[0]: v.split('：')[1].strip() for l in lst for v in l}

df = pd.DataFrame([d])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             id version        date         v1         v2  type      address
0  ZC0000218734   forth  2020-07-06  undefined  undefined  park  zhejiang...
```